# Aplicar el colorAccent a los diálogos descendientes de un AppCompatPreferenceActivity en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo un actividad de ajustes que hereda de `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` me encuentro que el color asignado en `ColorAccent` solo se muestra en los controles dentro de ella, es decir si un control abre un dialogo como es el caso de `listPreference` dentro del dialogo que muestra no hereda el `ColorAccent` de la actividad.

¿Cómo asignar/heredar el ColorAccent de la actividad en un listPreference?

Tener en cuenta compatibilidad entre versiones android `Ice-Cream-Sandwich Jelly-Bean, KitKat, Lollipop, Android M`

Comment: He encontrado eso mirare de implementarlo si funciona http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531707/android-how-to-change-listpreference-title-colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en la respuesta [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531707/android-how-to-change-listpreference-title-colour) y esa [otra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241380/applying-appcompat-theme-to-individual-preferences-in-a-preferencefragment)

En el `AndroidManifest.xml` a la creación de la actividad `settings`

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/settings_activity_title"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Settings" />
```

Crear el estilo en `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.Settings" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

Para los diálogos que se mostrarán dentro de la actividad

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog.MinWidth">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Añadir compatibilidad MaterialDesign en `values-21/styles.xml`

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog.MinWidth">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

### Otra manera compactada

En `styles.xml`

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>
```

Testeado en: Android L, Android M (falta KitKat y JellyBean)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199118/custom-dialog-size-to-match-theme-holo-light-dialog

Comment: Excelente compendio para aplicar el colorAccent!